# react-native-fbsdk not compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'

Tags: android, react-native, android-support-library, react-native-fbsdk

react-native version 0.51.0

react-native-fbsdk version 0.6.3 and I did try version 0.6.0

project run before install react-native-fbsdk
I do every steps in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-android-current

This is react-native-fbsdk/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+' // support react-native-v0.22-rc+
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+')
}
```

This is app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

and errors are...

```
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat:25.0.0
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.1
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1
Error:Error:line (19)Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat:25.0.0
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1
Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.1
```

Comment: try to update `Support Repository` from your android sdk manager. https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

Comment: the latest version is already installed

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this workaround while I'm not finding the right way to fix it.

Make this change to `node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle`:

```
//Before
dependencies {
    ...
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+')
}

//After
dependencies {
    ...
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0')
}
```

Maybe help you too.

Answer (score 0):

React Native Project : Go to `android/build.gradle` .
1 . All you have to do is add a new `maven` line to the allprojects section for `maven.google.com`
2. Add `resolutionStrategy` will help to restrict  `android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
         configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `com.android.support:appcompat` in build.gradle to

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```